# Istio egressgateway doesn't collect metrics with label `reporter=destination`

Tags: metrics, istio, istio-gateway, istio-prometheus

when app send a request to external service entry via egress gateway, the traffict should like

app -> egreegateway -> service entry

but however, the kiali didn't show the traffic from app to egressgateway

[image]

I checked that this is because of istio gateway proxy only collect metrics which has label `reporter=source`, but for a sidecar proxy, it also collect metrics with label `reporter=destination` except `reporter=source`

Anyone knows that is it possible to make gateway proxy collect metrics with `reporter=destination` too?

Many thanks!